# ASP.NET MVC TextBoxFor helper rendering empty when null

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I noticed that TextBoxFor helper renders empty if there is no model, like for instance when I have a CreateEdit ViewUserControl. When in Edit view fields are filled in, when in Create fields are empty but still rendered.

The problem is TextBoxFor does not accept different Id for its name (the same as LabelFor and others, but for LabelFor I have custom Html helpers).

So in some case we still have to use regular Html.TextBox helper. The problem is if I write this

```
    <%=Html.TextBox("postname", Model.PostCode.postname, new { @class = "postsDropDown" })%>
```

an error occurs in Create view (obviously).

So I have to do this:

```
    <% if (Model != null) %>
    <%=Html.TextBox("postname", Model.PostCode.postname, new { @class = "postsDropDown" })%>
    <% else %>
    <%=Html.TextBox("postname", null, new { @class = "postsDropDown" })%>
```

Now that is something which I don't like anymore (the IF's).

Is this the only way to do it? I know I could extend TextBoxFor helpers also but seems like so much trouble. In the end we will come to extending all of the "For" helpers but I think this should be done by ASP.NET MVC team already (built-in).

Comment: Please help me understand how will helper resolve the problem, as right now in current case Problem is while evaluating Model.PostCode as Model is null. So even if we write a helper and then if we are still using Model.PostCode it will throw an error on evaluation even before call is helper is made.

Comment: In my opinion this is a design problem on your part. There should be no reason for the model to be null.

Comment: @matt: When we are in the Create View the model is obviously null because we are creating new instance of an entity. I don't see how this could be any different. Providing an empty object to the model would be design problem, I guess.

Comment: @nitin: Well we could check the model properties in the helper and render accordingly.

Comment: @mare, Your model should never be null. In your case you should instantiate a empty object. If you consider pushing a null model to a view your view should not be strongly typed. Your view should be dumb and it has to assume that if it's strongly typed it will have a model of that type (not null).

Comment: Are you trying to use reflection and pass property name as string? Some thing like: <%=Html.TextBox("postname", "Model.PostCode.postname", new { @class = "postsDropDown" })%>

I think then it will work fine.

Comment: No Nitin you missed the point, but ok..

Comment: @Mattias: I just checked out Nerddinner example (because at the moment that's the only one I have available) and though they only have one Create view and one Create action in their Dinners controller, they indeed are instantiating an empty Dinner object for their Create view. So for now, I can confirm that in at least one case you are right. But I would need to verify that on more samples. So if you insist on it, please post an answer explaining why it should be like that and a best practice code sample for instantiating empty model. For instance, they are only setting EventDate...

Comment: @mare, Just google for open source asp.net mvc apps. It doesn't make sense to pass null as a model to a strongly typed view. Therefore you just don't do it. If you don't want a specific model for a view it shouldn't be strongly typed. But if it is strongly typed the view has to assume it isn't null.

Answer (score 0):

If `Model` is `null`, then trying to access `Model.PostCode.postname` will throw a NullReferenceException, so I don't think you'll be able to fix it in TextBoxFor. You could try doing something like `Model != null && Model.PostCode != null ? Model.PostCode.postname : null` but it's pretty nasty :-(